# What's the database format for WhatsApp Desktop for windows?

Tags: windows, database, file-types, instant-messaging, whatsapp

I'm trying to extract all of my WhatsApp messages with metadata for analysis, searching, graphing, e.t.c. Extraction of the Android database requires rooted access, so I'm trying to use the database created by the WhatsApp Desktop windows app.

I've located `messages.db` to be stored at

```
%AppData%\Local\Packages\5319275A.WhatsAppDesktop_cv1g1gvanyjgm\LocalState\messages.db
```

where the characters in the `5319275A.WhatsAppDesktop_cv1g1gvanyjgm` folder's name may be randomly generated.

However, I'm unsure what format messages.db is.

There's a `messages.db-shm` and a `messages.db-wal` present alongside `messages.db`, which suggests that they're temporary files created by sqlite, however I've tried opening `messages.db` as SQLite and SQLite reports that it's not an SQL database.

So, *what format does WhatsApp Desktop (for windows) use to store it's messages in `messages.db`?*

Comment: It's entirely possible that they are sqlite databases, but that the files are encrypted by the Whatsapp application before being written to disk.

Comment: It is an sqlite DB. It's a windows store app, so you may need to copy the DB files out of \Packages? Some digging on the internet says they're probably not encrypted, but that may have changed in the past few years. The android app does have a chat export under More options > More > Export chat, which sends an email with chats in .txt format, in case that will work for you

Comment: @mokubai yeah I think there's a chance that they're encrypted, I'll try to look for a key

Comment: @cpt.whale I'll look to see if I can find other similar databases under \Packages, but I'm pretty sure this is the right one. As for the chat export, that can only be done for one chat at a time (to the best of my knowledge) and also loses a large amount of metadata for each message

Comment: How to decrypt the "messages.db" file ?